# Custom Config Section Property C#

Tags: c#, app-config

I would like to configure custom in my app.config. How do i achieve this?  This is C# console applications.

can you help on this ?

```
<Configurations>
    <ApiSettings>
        <BaseUrl>http://localhost:62954</BaseUrl>
        <EndPoint>api/token</EndPoint>
        <PollingIntervalInSeconds>10</PollingIntervalInSeconds>
    </ApiSettings>
</Configurations>
```

I'm getting below exceptions.

[image]

Comment: You really need to be a little more verbose than this. What type of project? Why XML-Appsettings? How do you try to read them?

Comment: @Fildor, I have added some comments. Can you help on this ?

Comment: Include the code that raises the exception.